# What is the scope of the state for Spark Streaming's mapWithState?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, spark-streaming

With Spark Streaming, I can create a `DStream[(K, V)]` on which I can use `mapWithState` to maintain some state during stream processing. The `map` function is set up like this:

```
val mapFun =
  (key: K, maybeValue: Option[V], state: State[S]) => {
  // Do stuff
}
```

and then I can use:

```
val mappedStreamWithState = stream.mapWithState(StateSpec.function(mapFun))
```

My question now is: what is the scope of the `state`? Is it the key or the partition?

Let's say the stream comes from a Kafka topic that has 3 partitions but there can be 300 keys. To my understanding, each `RDD` in the stream has 3 partitions with approximately 100 keys each. Will there then be 3 states (one for each partition) or 300 states (one for each key)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am answering my own question so I can mark it as accepted, should another one have the same question.

**tl;dr:** The scope of the state is the partition, and there are more caveats when you depend on the key.

I investigated `mapWithState` quite a bit and here is what I found out:

- `mapWithState` only works on a `DStream[(A, B)]`. So far so good.
- The incoming stream that is produced with `mapWithState` is implicitly partitioned by the key. From what I found out so far, the partition count depends on the number of worker tasks available. E.g., running it in `local[*]` mode on a CPU with 8 threads yields 8 partitions.
- The scope of the state is the partition, so if you depend on the key, you should add some mapping to the state, e.g., using a `Map[TKey, TStateForTheKey]`
- Doing something like a `stream.repartition(1).mapWithState(...)` is futile
- If you need to make sure that two keys are in one partition, i.e., if you want to calculate some values from measuring data channels depending on each other, you have to assign a unique key to them, this makes sure they go into the same partition

So, let's say you have data in a `DStream[(String, Int)]` like this:

```
foo,1
bar,8
foo,23
quux,423
bletch,42
bar,5
```

and you need to make sure that `foo` and `bar` are processed together and `quux` and `bletch` are, you need to do something like this:

```
stream.
  flatMap {
    case (k, v) if Seq("foo", "bar").contains(k)     => Some("foobar" -> (k, v))
    case (k, v) if Seq("quux", "bletch").contains(k) => Some("quuxbletch" -> (k, v))
    case _                                           => None
  }.
  mapWithState(StateSpec.function(myFunc))
```

And your mapping function must be like:

```
val myFunc = (key: String, maybeRecord: Option[(String, Int)], state: State[Something]) => {
  // Do something with the record
}
```